# The Great Plugin Nomenclature Contest of 2011

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

It's been a while since I've done a bounty challenge, so here's another.  Same basic rules: 1 answer per person, most creative/useful/helpful/entertaining answer wins. This time around, the award will be 50 reputation points via a [Bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty).

This challenge is for my in-development plugin, **Crossfire**.

### Plugin Purpose

Allows authors of multiple sites on a multisite network to cross-post their content from one site to another.

### How it Works

Authors write a post as usual on the primary site.  Then they select the sites to cross-post from a meta box.  WordPress uses a custom post type to keep track of the cross-posted content on the sister sites.

### Endgame

- Visitors to both the main site and the sister sites will see the new post at the top of the page.
- Comments on one site are automatically mirrored to all the others.
- Feed subscribers will only see the new post in the original site's feed.

As I said, the plugin will be called **Crossfire**, but I need a creative name for the  custom post type used on sister sites (where the post content is imported).  Calling them "posts" isn't accurate since they won't show up in the site's feed.

So, give me your best ideas and the *best* of the best will be awarded 50 reputation points!

Contest ends Friday, April 23 at 19:00 UTC (12:00 Pacific).

Comment: Will there be a UI exposed on the 'sister' site(s) for this CPT?

Comment: Yes. You'll be able to manage the status and other attachments to the CPT from within the sister site ... there will also be hooks for SEO tools since the post will be visible on the front page, have a URL for the sister site, etc. It just pulls in content and comments from the "main" site.

Comment: You should add a bounty ,) ...

Comment: Questions must be open for 2 days before you can add a bounty, but I will as promised.

Comment: As promised, a 50-point bounty has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ricochet**

After all, this custom post type is kind of rebounding off one network site to another. Plus it's a bit of a play on words based on your plugin's name.

Comment: One of my favorite so far, actually. Plays on the plugin name and everything!

Answer (score 8):

SPARKS

(I was thinking Flames....but that's kinda negative in the interwebs world, no?)

Is there a way to not have to post 30 characters??

Comment: Dagnabit! I couldn't think of anything better, so I wont even try

Comment: Thanks...it was the first thing that popped into my head. Sparks start fires, these sparks start crossfire conversations...... meh, that was my thinking at least!

Answer (score 7):

**Crossposts**.

Simple, easy, accurate. They are posts from another site, crossposted to this site. Also fits with the name of your plugin.

Generally speaking, it's best to use descriptive names from other contexts. A lot of people understand the idea of "crossposting", which is obviously why you picked the plugin name. For a post_type, "crossposts" makes sense here, and people will recognize it from other contexts they've used it in.

Comment: I was going to suggest this also, if we were allowed more than one answer. So, +1 from me!

Answer (score 5):

## **FirePost**

Comment: Much more creative than CFpost, I'll give you that :-)

Answer (score 4):

**network-wide-post**

People not really into web will grasp this easier.

Answer (score 3):

**DUPLEX**

What do you think? :)

Answer (score 3):

**Reflection**

...because the post is being *mirrored*.

Comment: Of the ones posted so far, I think I like this one best. It makes sense as a plural post type (I.e., "four Reflections"; as opposed to something like "four Ricochets", "four Site 2 Posts" or "four Duplexes") and is descriptive of what the post actually is (I.e., a mirrored copy).

Answer (score 3):

I tend to veer more towards descriptive when picking things like this, so I'd suggest:

**Network Post**

Ultimately you're creating networks with this plugin, and calling it as such will reduce cognitive dissonance for admin users trying to figure out where all these new posts came from...

(Cool plugin idea, btw!)

Answer (score 3):

Snipes! Because someone's shooting their content at you from a distance :)

Answer (score 2):

### **CFpost**

*admittedly not very creative*

Answer (score 2):

maybe **CrossPoster** ... or **WidePoster**.

Answer (score 2):

Multipost.

Because … it is posted on multiple sites. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Bridge Post

since it bridges across multiple sites.

Answer (score 2):

**Riposte**

A play on post and the *attaaack..!* theme that CrossFire conjures up for me.

**CrossFlame**

If CrossFire is the plural, then CrossFlame seems like the logical singular.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

Site 2 Post

or

Web 2 Post

Answer (score 1):

XPost, XSPost, XSP

Idea from XSS. Cross Site Posting -> XSPost

Answer (score 1):

**cross-press**

bit of a play on your plugin name and wordpress

Comment: Same issue with edelwater's suggestion -- OP is asking for a post-type name, not a plugin name. The *press convention is used more for systems producing content (i.e., plugins), not the content type itself.